# Width of UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, storyboard, xcode6

I've project which is based on storyboard and on one of the views I've placed UITableView with UIViewTableViewCell (style Right Detail).

[image]

In Xcode everything looks OK, but when I launch application on simulator or device, the the table cell looks too wide.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions what could be reason of this strange behavior? What should I change to get cell be full visible?

EDIT:

I'm attaching cellforRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTableCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: it's working same as iPhone4  ?

Comment: Could you post the code from cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @ZeMoon I've edited main question.

Comment: Where is the title being set? Also, there seems to be another label with the text "De..." appearing. Where and how have you set this label?

Comment: Earlier I put wrong screen (now updated). I use default style 'Right Details' without setting my custom text to title or detail. As you can see Detail is out of the screen and it's my main problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put the same width for your custom cell, as the width of a UITableView?

[image]

Also, have you managed your "Delete" Label size properly (using autolayout or autoresizing).
With new iPhone 6, we have to pay attention to widtch as well, just like with different heights, when iPhone 5 was introduced.

And I can see from those two screenshots you posted that you develop using iPhone6 sized ViewController and running it on iPhone5.

Im prety sure you didn't manage Autolayout / Autoresizing as you should.

Try doing this, for your "Delete" label:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your advices. Initially in my question I put wrong first screen (now updated). I'm using iPhone 4.7". In storyboard I've checked 'Use Auto Layout' and 'Use Size Classes'. In my example I remove all my custom filed in cell and set only predefined in Xcode 'Right Detail' style without setting any custom values in it. As you can see 'Detail' is out of screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where the content on the right hand side of my tableView was being cut off.

The reason being, I had set the `Autolayout` constraints correctly for the views inside my custom tableViewCell. However, I had not set the `AutoLayoutConstraints` for the tableView itself. Therefore the UITableView wasn't being constrained correctly and in my case was too large.